# Does aes_string() change any default settings in R? A problem with R Shiny and ggplot input$ interaction

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, aes

I'm creating a Shiny app in Rstudio and I had trouble inserting an input$char into a ggplot boxplot, where input$char was the variable for y-axis, and the x-axis was not an input variable, but instead from the data frame. The issue was that the data wouldn't appear in the graph, but the input function of the dropdown menu still changed the y-axis in the graph when the app was loaded.
Example code:

```
g = reactive({ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Species, y=input$ybox))+ theme(legend.position = "top")})
output$Boxplot = renderPlot(g() + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Species)) + scale_fill_brewer(palette 
  = "Set2"))
```

I found through another post on here that aes_string() could fix the problem, and it did. Where aes is in ggplot, I fixed the error with aes_string() and let x="Species" in the function....

except now all of my other variables are not recognized in the rest of my shiny app! Where ever there is Species or another input$char variable, they are not recognized and I receive an error. Either object 'Species' not found, or unused arguments 'input$char;,...,'Species'.

Example code that gives error:

```
  selection = reactive({iris[, aes(c(input$xcol, input$ycol, 'Species'))]}) 
  fit = reactive({knn3(Species ~ ., data=selection(), k = input$K)}) 
  output$KNNplot = renderPlot({decisionplot(fit(), selection(), class=Species,main=paste('Decision Boundary for KNN (',input$K,')', sep=' '))})
```

Is there any way I can have both a solution to the ggplot error and for the rest of my app to still work?

Edit (Reproducible code):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(lattice)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(nnet)
library(naivebayes)
library(e1071)
library(randomForest)
library(MASS)

# function for decisionplot.R
decisionplot <- function(model, data, class = NULL, predict_type = "class",
                         resolution = 100, showgrid = TRUE, ...) {
  
  if(!is.null(class)) cl <- data[,class] else cl <- 1
  data <- data[,1:2]
  k <- length(unique(cl))
  
  plot(data, col = as.integer(cl)+1L, pch = as.integer(cl)+1L, ...)
  
  # make grid
  r <- sapply(data, range, na.rm = TRUE)
  xs <- seq(r[1,1], r[2,1], length.out = resolution)
  ys <- seq(r[1,2], r[2,2], length.out = resolution)
  g <- cbind(rep(xs, each=resolution), rep(ys, time = resolution))
  colnames(g) <- colnames(r)
  g <- as.data.frame(g)
  
  ### guess how to get class labels from predict
  ### (unfortunately not very consistent between models)
  p <- predict(model, g, type = predict_type)
  if(is.list(p)) p <- p$class
  p <- as.factor(p)
  
  if(showgrid) points(g, col = as.integer(p)+1L, pch = ".")
  
  z <- matrix(as.integer(p), nrow = resolution, byrow = TRUE)
  contour(xs, ys, z, add = TRUE, drawlabels = FALSE,
          lwd = 2, levels = (1:(k-1))+.5)
  
  invisible(z)
}

ui = fluidPage(
  navlistPanel(
    tabPanel("Descriptive Statistics",
             fluidRow(
               column(6,
                      wellPanel(selectInput('ybox', 'Y Variable', names(iris)[1:4], selected = names(iris)[[2]])),
                      plotOutput('Boxplot'))),
              fluidRow(
               column(12, 
                      wellPanel(selectInput('xdens', 'X Variable', names(iris)[1:4], selected= names(iris)[2])),
                      plotOutput("Densplot")))),
    tabPanel("Naive Bayes Classifier",
           wellPanel(selectInput('xcol5', 'X Variable', names(iris)[1:4], selected = names(iris)[[1]]),
                     selectInput('ycol5', 'Y Variable', names(iris)[1:4], selected = names(iris)[[2]])),
           plotOutput('NBplot'))
  
    ))

server = function(input, output) {
   
  # Boxplot
  g = reactive({ggplot(data=iris, aes_(x='Species', y=iris[[as.name(input$ybox)]]))+ theme(legend.position = "top")})
  output$Boxplot = renderPlot(g() + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Species)) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") + ylab(input$ybox))
  
  
  # Densityplot
  c = reactive({ggplot(iris, aes_(iris[[as.name(input$xdens)]]))})
  mu = reactive({ddply(iris, "Species", summarise, grp.mean=mean(c()))})
  dc = reactive({c() + geom_density(kernel="gaussian", aes(color=Species, fill=Species), alpha=0.4) +
      geom_vline(data=mu(), aes(xintercept=mu()$grp.mean, color=Species),linetype="dashed") +
      theme(legend.position = "top") + xlab(input$xdens)})
  output$Densplot = renderPlot({dc() + scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2") + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")})
  
  
  #example model
  selection5 = reactive({iris[, c(input$xcol5, input$ycol5, 'Species')]}) 
  fit5 = reactive({naive_bayes(Species ~ ., data=selection5(), usekernel = T)})
  output$NBplot = renderPlot({decisionplot(fit5(), selection5(), class = "Species",
                                           main = "Decision Boundary for Naive Bayes Classifier")})
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Species, y= .data[[input$ybox]])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `selection5` was an issue.  The following code gives a reactive data frame.

```
  #example model
  selection5 <- reactive({
    # df <- iris[, c(input$xcol5, input$ycol5, 'Species')] ## this call does not work
    df <- data.frame(x=iris[[input$xcol5]], y=iris[[input$ycol5]], Species=iris[, "Species"])
  })
```

Comment: Ok, but in doing that I had to change the rest of my plot for it to recognize Species and render a plot. For example, I had to change fill=Species to fill=iris[['Species']]. And the rest of my models, like the KNN plot, still don't recognize input$'s or Species, when they used to before I added these ggplot elements to my app.

Comment: Thank you, but I guess the biggest part of my problem is understanding why adding aes_string() and these ggplots basically broke my app and made all the previously recognizable inputs no longer recognizable to the rest of my functions :(

Comment: `aes_string()` uses standard evaluation - `aes_string(x = "mpg", y = "wt")`, while `aes()` uses non-standard evaluation - `aes(x = mpg, y = wt)`.  You could also try `aes_()`, as it works better in some situations.

Comment: Yes! That helped a little, thank you. In ggplot I used aes_(x='Species', y=iris[[as.name(input$ybox)]]) and then in geom_boxplot I used aes(fill=Species). However, my KNN plot (as well as the others) still give error "unused arguments input$,...,'Species'". I took off quotes on Species and it said object not found. I added iris[[as.name()]] to the inputs and that generated the unused arguments error, too. Do you know how I could fix this, also?

Comment: Ok, I've added some code to create the problem. I've isolated the problem to the density plot. If I comment it out of the code all of my plots work, but with it in, the input$s and Species for naive bayes and other formulas aren't recognized.

Comment: I'm still not sure why density plot effects my other plots (I also don't know if that's really the truth), but using your method of creating the data frame I think will do the trick! The error you're getting is due to the order of the variables in the dataframe. By switching Species to the last column, the plot works!

Comment: @uh_, I updated the code.  Everything works fine for me.